# Programa em Python que gere um quadrado de caracteres com diagonal principal

Tags: python, string, loop, matriz

Estou tentando fazer um programa que dado um valor, gere um "quadrado" de n linhas e n colunas que tenha caracteres `:` nas posições da diagonal principal e os caracteres `+` nas demais posições.

Por exemplo, n = 5:

```
:++++
+:+++
++:++
+++:+
++++:
```

A lógica está correta, contudo, estou com problemas na formatação do quadrado. Alguém pode me ajudar por favor?

```
n = 0
i = 0
j = 0

n = int(input("Digite um número: "))

if n > 0:
    print("Desenho")
    for i in range(1, n):
        for j in range(1, n):
            if i != j:
                print("+", end="")
            else:
                print(":", end="")
                print()
else:
    print("Numero menor ou igual a zero, programa abortado!")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O `print()` que faz a quebra de linha deve estar fora do `else` - na verdade deve estar fora do `for` interno também, pois você só deve mudar de linha depois que imprimiu todos os caracteres dela.

Além disso, um [`range`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#typesseq-range) não inclui o valor final, então `range(1, n)` vai de 1 a n - 1, ou seja, o *loop* fará uma iteração a menos. No caso, basta omitir o primeiro parâmetro, fazendo apenas `range(n)`, que o início será o zero:

```
n = int(input("Digite um número: "))
if n > 0:
    print("Desenho")
    for i in range(n):
        for j in range(n):
            if i != j:
                print("+", end="")
            else:
                print(":", end="")
        print() # fora do else, dentro do for externo
```

Repare também que não precisa declarar todas as variáveis no início, atribuindo um valor qualquer que será descartado logo em seguida. Crie-as apenas quando precisar delas.

Comment: Deu certinho, muito obrigado!!!

Comment: @MatheusGuerreiro Se a resposta resolveu o seu problema, vc pode aceitá-la, [**veja aqui**](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1078/112052) como e porque fazê-lo. Não é obrigatório, mas é uma boa prática do site, para indicar a futuros visitantes que aquilo resolveu o problema. E quando tiver 15 pontos, [**vc também poderá votar**](/help/privileges/vote-up) na resposta caso tenha achado útil